# Extract traffic information from MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

I am new to Android and followed a tutorial to display [MapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview).

The MapView also displays traffic information using the a method `mapview.setTraffic(true)`.

The MapView displays traffic information as lines red, green and yellow.
My question here is it possible to extract this traffic information?

I am trying to capture this traffic information and then convert it as audio and relay it to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't separate the traffic information because it comes through on rasterized tiles.